# robots txt disallow wild card

Tags: web-crawler, robots.txt

I am having trouble stopping google crawling a few urls which cause errors.

I want to stop

- /project/123984932842/download/pdf
- /project/123984932842/download/zip

but allow

- /project/123984932842
- /project/123984932842/flat

I tried project/*/download/pdf but it doesn't seem to work. Does anyone know what would?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Do you have a `/` at the beginning of the `Disallow:` line?

```
User-agent: googlebot
Disallow: /project/*/download/pdf
```

Comment: How would that be different than Allowing?
I don't understand what changes /*/download/pdf

It's still disallowed. You can't be serious wildcard is used to disallow?

At least it could be in Allow or something?

Answer (score 1):

The *original* robots.txt specification doesn't define any wildcards, but Google (and some others) added them to their parsers. <s>However, I guess you don't need them for your case anyway</s> (as Jim noted, this was wrong). The following robots.txt (using the [`*` wildcard](https://developers.google.com/webmasters/control-crawl-index/docs/robots_txt)) should do the job:

```
User-agent: Googlebot
Disallow: /project/*/download
```

Comment: That's not true at all. The robots.txt specification says that a disallow line blocks *url prefixes*. So `Disallow: download/pdf` wouldn't do anything. See http://www.robotstxt.org/robotstxt.html

Comment: @Jim: Wow, I thought that if the leading slash is omitted, the "prefix" could start *anywhere* in the URL path. So, would `Disallow: /foo` and `Disallow: foo` be equivalent? Or would the latter one be incorrect?

Comment: @JimMischel Why you didn't place /project/*/download in Allow: ?
With this you are still disallowing.